# How to set the default module in zend framework 1

Tags: zend-framework

How to set the default module in zend 1.* ?

my code in appilication.ini

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "agency"
```

Error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception'
>   with message 'No default controller directory registered with front
>   controller' in
>   D:\Hicham2016\rentcar\vendor\zendframework\zendframework1\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php
>   on line 99

Comment: I would open D:\Hicham2016\rentcar\vendor\zendframework\zendframework1\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php and look at the source to see where it's looking. Better yet -- don't know if this is an option for you or not -- forget ZF1 and use ZF2 instead. Especially if this is a new project.

Answer (score 0):

First try

```
resources.frontcontroller.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
```

and maybe you also have to set:

```
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/agency/controllers"
resources.frontController.defaultControllerName = "default"
resources.frontController.defaultAction = "home"
```

- "defaultControllerName" correspondes to DefaultController.php
- "defaultAction" to homeAction().

If that does not work try to override the constructor of the agency module bootstrap

```
public function __construct($application)
{
    parent::__construct($application);
    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $frontController->addControllerDirectory(__DIR__ . '/controllers', 'agency');
}
```

Reference

- [Zend_Application_Resource_Frontcontroller docs](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.frontcontroller)